# Maximum dimension of column space and row space of a $M\times N$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say we have a $M\times N$ matrix of real numbers. What is the maximum dimension of the column space and the row space for this matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum dimension of the column space and the row space for this matrix is $\min(M,N)$.